# How to configure Exchange external mail in Plesk for a domain?

Tags: exchange, email-server, plesk

I have a customer using external email service. (Exchange from Acens company in Spain).

I have migrated his domain and website to my server from the old hosting provider and I have tried to configure the external email in Plesk using their explanation:

They said to configure the DNS zone like so:

```
he.sleepbcn.com MX 10   smtp.he.sleepbcn.com.   
he.sleepbcn.com MX 20   mx2.dominioabsoluto.com.    
he.sleepbcn.com TXT v=spf1 ip4:217.116.0.0/24 ip4:217.116.1.0/24 ip4:77.240.117.0/24 ~all   
_autodiscover._tcp.he.sleepbcn.com  SRV 0 5 443 autodiscover.he2007.es. 
smtp.he.sleepbcn.com    A   217.116.0.227
```

So I have done that, you can see the full DNS zone in Plesk for the domain in this screenshot:

http://snag.gy/l6PPS.jpg

I have also disabled Plesk email service for that domain, because I think it is the correct thing to do since it is going to use external mail service.

I have also restarted some server services: Plesk, Httpd, Postfix and Courier.

The support from Acens say that DNS settings look fine but when I try to send a email to that domain I get the following error:

http://pastebin.com/UXwG9BMC (note that I've replaced the original domain in the email with "example.com" and also my gmail account to avoid spam)

So I would ask two things, one, does anyone know what's wrong? why is it not working already? And second, does anyone know any good tutorial on this topic? I can't imagine nobody else has done this before.

Comment: Contact the external email provider.

Comment: Are you a web hoster or a DNS hoster?

Comment: MichaelHampton did that, joequerty I provide my dedicated server as shared hosting for my own customers. And one uses external mail service.

Answer (score 1):

The MX record for sleepbcn.com is `mail.sleepbcn.com`. Is the host named `mail.sleepbcn.com` running an email server that is configured to be authoritative for the sleepbcn.com domain? If not, then that's your problem.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>cd\

C:\>nslookup
Default Server:  w2k8r2dhcpdns1.home.local
Address:  192.168.1.2

> set q=mx
> sleepbcn.com
Server:  w2k8r2dhcpdns1.home.local
Address:  192.168.1.2

sleepbcn.com
        primary name server = ns2.heavydots.com
        responsible mail addr = abonanni.me.com
        serial  = 2015102901
        refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 10800 (3 hours)
> he.sleepbcn.com
Server:  w2k8r2dhcpdns1.home.local
Address:  192.168.1.2

Non-authoritative answer:
he.sleepbcn.com MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = smtp.he.sleepbcn.com
he.sleepbcn.com MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = mx2.dominioabsoluto.com

smtp.he.sleepbcn.com    internet address = 217.116.0.227
mx2.dominioabsoluto.com internet address = 217.116.0.162
>
```

Comment: I see, I was thinking about that, I have added DNS settings that the provider told me, but I haven't deleted the default MX entry that Plesk had in the first place. I'll try to delete it and see what happens. mail.sleepbcn.com was Plesk default's but they said to add the other to that start with "he."

Comment: I have removed `sleepbcn.com. IN MX (10) mail.sleepbcn.com.` and `sleepbcn.com. IN TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all` but still not working. Not sure if I had to remove the last one. Now when I check for MX with some tool it says the domain has no MX record, but it does have the two other MX records I have added but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Right, because he.sleepbcn.com is a subdomain of sleepbcn.com. You need an MX record for sleepbcn.com, not he.sleepbcn.com.

Comment: I really don't know why the provider told me to add the rules prefixing the domain with "he", but that's what they said. You can see in the question the exact DNS settings they told me to add. So I've added that in the main DNS zone of the domain. It is not a subdomain, it's jut that I've prefixed all the rules with "he". So I have no idea what other DNS setting I must change, you can see full DNS list in the screenshot.

Comment: I did look at the screenshot and I'm sorry to be the one to break the news to you, but `he.sleepbcn.com` is a subdomain of `sleepbcn.com` and your MX record is valid for `he.sleepbcn.com`, not for `sleepbcn.com`. See the nslookup results I just added to my answer.

Comment: I see. But then what is wrong with the configuration? The provider told me to add exactly those entries, as a subdomain. What should I do now so when sending mails to a account on that domain, the external service will handle it? Okay I've sent a mail to `<account>@he.sleepbcn.com` including the subdomain and did not gave any error yet. So well I really don't understand, what does this mean that the provider wants me to use the subdomain instead? Then how will a email to `<account>@sleepbcn.com` reach `<account>@he.sleepbcn.com` ? Damn I'll end up calling those guys on phone..

Comment: You lost me. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to setup MX records and email for `sleepbcn.com` or `he.sleepbcn.com`?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm just thinking.. are they that crazy that they want me to use the subdomain? The only way I think of to make it work leaving the subdomain, is to re-activate the mail service on the main domain, and foward mails sent to accounts on the main domain, to accounts on the subdomain. I wonder if this was the way they had it configured in the previous provider. Or maybe I also wonder if I add all those settings they told me but instead of putting it as subdomain, to put it as configuration on the main domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30885/discussion-between-alexandru-trandafir-catalin-and-joeqwerty).

Comment: Sorry for such a mess. I think I've finally understood the situation. I think they wanted me to use the subdomain, not the main domain. Don't know why it was configured like this in the old hosting. But they want to do the same here. So what I'm going to do is just what I said, re-enable Plesk mail on the main domain, and forward mails to the subdomain. Because otherwise they should have given me MX records for the main domain not the subdomain, isn't it?